# Why am I not able to use a global variable from Flask program to another python file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, flask, web-deployment

I am trying to use a dictionary from file1 in another file2, but in file2 it prints empty dictionary. Can you please help me with the reason, thanks in advance.

Following is my file1:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
global user_pincode
user_pincode={}
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
       global user_pincode
       #user_pincode getting updated here

@app.route('/delete', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def delete():
       global user_pincode
       #user_pincode getting updated here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Following is my file2:

```
import file1
print(file1.user_pincode)
```

Comment: When do you run file2? At the same time? At different times?

Comment: When you import a file, python is importing the source file, in this case user_pincode is set to {}. If you want to exchange data between two running programs, think about writing user_pincode to a file. The flask app writes updated data and the "file2" reads it.

Answer (score 1):

You did `import file1`

That's why `file1.user_pincode` is equal to `{}`

But you did not call any function that could change the value.

Take a look.

A. Let's modify function `delete` in `file1`

```py
@app.route('/delete', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def delete():
    #    global user_pincode 
       user_pincode['key'] = 'delete'
```

B. Modify caller module `main.py`:

```py
import file1
print(file1.user_pincode)
file1.delete()
print(file1.user_pincode)
```

C. Run it:

```sh
python main.py 
{}
{'key': 'delete'}
```

Everything as expected.

Note that `global` is not needed anywhere for `dict`.

Comment: Hi, the functions 'index()' and 'delete()' are triggered using the website as it takes input from there and updates 'user_pincode'. If I trigger these functions in file2, the code in that function will run again but will not get any input.

Comment: Here is the sequence:
1. I run file1, opens my website and give some inputs. These inputs are used to update the dictionary 'user_pincode'.
2. Then I run file2, to utilize the updated dictionary for further processing.
Is there any other option instead of writing the data in a text file say, or database? Like using python data types only?

Comment: @vandit_left_join `2. Then I run file2` - does that means that you run another process `python file2` ?

Comment: Yes, correct! Is this something not supported by Flask, or shall I avoid this?

Comment: @vandit_left_join it's not supported by python itself. You run 2 independent python processes in one of them web application executing and in another you try to look in memory of other process

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is an compile time/runtime issue.

The global variable is initialized as empty dictionary at compile time. Your file2 is evaluated at compile time so it prints an empty dict.

What is your use case anyway? If you'd like to have a value surviving a single request you will probably have to store it in some file or database.

Comment: Hey, I think you are very close to answer my query, here is the sequence:
1. I run file1, opens my website and give some inputs. These inputs are used to update the dictionary 'user_pincode'.
2. Then I run file2, to utilize the updated dictionary for further processing.
Is there any other option instead of writing the data in a text file say, or database? Like using python data types only?

Comment: Hello back, from what you write I suggest using a key value store like [simplekv](https://pythonhosted.org/simplekv/). You will need to install a memcached though in order to make it work if you do not like to use the pure file system.